# Map two collections into keys and values

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I have Collection A like this...

```php
[
    "Gender",
    "Name",
    "Role",
],
```

... and I have a Collection B from a model instance like this...

```json
[
       App\Models\Staff {
         id: 11,
         name: "John Doe",
         gender: 'Male',
         2: "role",
         role: App\Models\Role {
           id: 1,
           name: "Director",
         },
       },

       App\Models\Staff {
         id: 22,
         name: "Jane Doe",
         gender: 'Female',
         2: "role",
         role: App\Models\Role {
           id: 2,
           name: "Company Secretary",
         },
       },
     ],
```

How can I get the two combined in a way that I have Collection C like this...

```php
[
    [
         "Gender" => 'Male',
         "Name" => 'John Doe',
         "Role" => 'Director',
    ],
    [
         "Gender" => 'Female',
         "Name" => 'Jane Doe',
         "Role" => 'Company Secretary',
    ],
]
```

I have tried a few things so far including this as a starting point.

```php
return $collectionB->map(function ($b) use ($collectionA) {
    return $collectionA->map(function ($a) use ($b) {
        return [
            $a => $b['gender'],
            $a => $b['name'],
            $a => $b['role']['name'],
        ];
    })->all();
})->all();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this by single `map()` function

```php
$data = [
    [
        'id' => 11,
        'name' => "John Doe",
        'gender' => "Male",
        "role" => [
            "id" => 1,
            "name" => 'Director',
        ]
    ],
    [
        'id' => 22,
        'name' => "John Doe",
        'gender' => "Male",
        "role" => [
            "id" => 2,
            "name" => 'Company Secretary',
        ]
    ]
];

$keys = [
    "Gender",
    "Name",
    "Role",
];

$data = collect($data)->map(function ($row) use ($keys) {
    return [
        $keys[0] => $row['gender'],
        $keys[1] => $row['name'],
        $keys[2] => $row['role']['name'] ?? '',
    ];
});


return $data;
```

output of this is

```json
[{
        "Gender": "Male",
        "Name": "John Doe",
        "Role": "Director"
    },
    {
        "Gender": "Male",
        "Name": "John Doe",
        "Role": "Company Secretary"
    }
]
```

Comment: I could do this if I hard-coded the keys to name, gender, role etc. however these values are dynamic and are coming from a JSON column in the database. My ultimate goal with this is to make it as dynamic as possible so as I can pass in a "field" key so the code can just loop through each header, loop through each record and map it to its corresponding header without knowing the individual names of each.

Comment: @riderofrohan07 why you need this ?